# Encoded target column shows only one category?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multilabel-classification, encoder

I am working on multiclass classification problem. My target column has 4 classes as Low, medium, high and very high. When I am trying to encode it, I am getting only 0 as value_counts(). I am not sure, why.

```
value count in original data frame is :
High         18767
Very High    15856
Medium        9212
Low           5067
Name: physician_segment, dtype: int64
```

I have tried below methods to encode my target column:

```
Using replace() method :

target_enc = {'Low':0,'Medium':1,'High':2,'Very High':3}
df1['physician_segment'] = df1['physician_segment'].astype(object)
df1['physician_segment'] = df1['physician_segment'].replace(target_enc)
df1['physician_segment'].value_counts()
0    48902
Name: physician_segment, dtype: int64

using factorize method():
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype 
df1['physician_segment'] = df1['physician_segment'].factorize()[0]
df1['physician_segment'].value_counts()
0    48902
Name: physician_segment, dtype: int64

Using Label Encoder :
from sklearn import preprocessing
labelencoder= LabelEncoder() 
df1['physician_segment'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df1['physician_segment']) df1['physician_segment'].value_counts()
0    48902
Name: physician_segment, dtype: int64
```

In all these three techniques, I am getting only one class as **0**, length of dataframe is **48902**.

Can someone please point out, what I am doing wrong.
I want my target column to have values as **0, 1, 2, 3**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
target_enc = {'Low':0,'Medium':1,'High':2,'Very High':3}
df1['physician_segment'] = df1['physician_segment'].astype(object)
```

After that create/define a function:-

```
def func(val):
    if val in target_enc.keys():
        return target_enc[val]
```

and finally use `apply()` method:-

```
df1['physician_segment']=df1['physician_segment'].apply(func)
```

Now if you print `df1['physician_segment'].value_counts()` you will get correct output

Comment: Thanks @Anurag. could you please elaborate on the issue I was facing? Was it because, the encoding techniques were not getting applied to each row?

Comment: well `replace()` method is working fine on my side..I am currently using pandas `1.2.2`...and even your code looks fine